# C#.net dynamically define Eval statements

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, itemtemplate

I am creating a report viewer where I do not know, in advance, what the query powering the report looks like (it is created using a separate report builder). I am using a set of `Telerik` controls to show the output when the "report is run" (i.e. query is executed and a `System.Data.DataTable` is returned). For raw data I am using a `DataGrid` which is fine since it automatically generates columns and everything works properly but I am also trying to generate a more visually appealing/readable version that is laid out vertically. I started with the example seen [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/listview/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx#qsf-demo-source) , but the problem is in the example the objects being displayed are known in advance and they utilize `#Eval("")` statements in the `ItemTemplate`. In my case I do not know what the columns names are so is there a way to dynamically rename the column reference in the `Eval` at run-time (on need `datasource` or something)? Or is there a better approach to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

I've used Telerik and RadGrid controls for a while. While I've never done anything like this, you should be able to call a method that returns a string instead of the Eval inside your server tags for the column content.

so instead of

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
    <%# Eval("MyColumnName") %>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

something like

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
    <%# GetColumn1Data() %>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

public string GetColumn1Data()
{
    return DataSet.Column1.ToString(); //pseudo code
}
```

You should be able to reference your dataset by index, maybe make a whole bunch of templatecolumns and hide them dynamically if the data is not there and they are not needed

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ItemDataBound event to access the template column (http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-accessing-cells-and-rows.html) and put whatever data you want in it, e.g., in a LiteralControl. This event gives you access to the data item associated with the row, so you can extract whatever you have.